# Normal calling object inside Model VS fetchAll()

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

Im new to zendframework & zend db..any help will be great!!

(Normal Way)
Lets say i want to get data..so im using this

Inside Controller

```
$db = new Studentfinance_Model_DbTable_FeeItem();
$data =$this->db->getDate();
```

Inside Model

```
protected $_name = 'tbl_foo_foo';
protected $_primary = "foo_id";

public function getData() {
        $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
        $selectData = $db->select()
        ->from(array('a'=>$this->_name))
        ->joinLeft(array('c'=>'tbl_bar'), 'c.idBar = a.id',array('DefinitionDesc','Status'))
        ->group('a.id')
        $fc_cat = $db->fetchAll($selectData);
        return($fc_cat);
    }
```

For Above line of code...i understand the way its work..
But for below..i have a bit problem  to understand..same concept..the purpose to get the data

inside controller/form

```
$feeCategoryDb = new Studentfinance_Model_DbTable_FeeCategory();
$listData = $feeCategoryDb->fetchAll();
```

i try to find function fetchAll()...but i dont find it inside Model FeeCategory...can someone explainn this

Answer (score 0):

$feeCategoryDb->getData() already sets up the query and runs "fetchAll" and returns the results. So all you need to do is:

```
$feeCategoryDb = new Studentfinance_Model_DbTable_FeeCategory();
$listData = $feeCategoryDb->getData();
```